# PersonAccount. Can I access and write in standard Contact's field?

Tags: account, fields, standard-objects, person-accounts, standard-field

I'm trying to write some standard Contact's fields e.g. `MobilePhone` and `Email` (I'm new to this object), when I create a new PersonAccount.

For example using an Anonymous window I tried with this code:

```
Account acc = new Account(FirstName='User', 
                         LastName= 'System',
                         MobilePhone=33900000,
                         Email = 'a@a.com'
);
insert acc;
```

I receive this error: "Field does not exist: MobilePhone on Account".

How is possible to write standard Contacts's field when creating a PersonAccount?

Answer (score 0):

You use the Person fields:

```
Account acc = new Account(FirstName='User', 
                         LastName= 'System',
                         PersonMobilePhone='33900000',
                         PersonEmail = 'a@a.com'
);
insert acc;
```

Comment: Thank you! In general, Can I access Contact's standard fields? e.g. Description, Salutation...or any other standard field?

Comment: @sdfcwolf I believe you can access most, if not all, the standard fields, plus you can access any custom field (use `CustomField__pc` instead of `CustomField__c`).